# Perspective transform on a raster image in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, raster, perspective

All I want is the Illustrator equivalent of what right-click -> Perspective does in Photoshop. Normally I would just use the Free Transform Tool, but it doesn't appear to let me do it with an imported raster image like it does so nicely on a vector.

I also don't need the Perspective Grid to snap to or anything like that, what am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add an *Envelope Mesh*.

`Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh` and choose 1 row and 1 column and click `OK`.

Then you can distort the envelope (which contains the raster image).

Alternatively, for simpler and symmetric perspective distorts you can use `Make with Warp` and select any warp. If you then adjust Bend to 0 %, you can use the Horizontal and Vertical sliders to adjust the perspective warp. This only works if the vanishing point is on either the horizontal or vertical central axis of the image, though, or compensate with Shear afterwards.

Note: this only works with embedded images, not linked. If you're using linked image files, you'll have to first embed the image.

Comment: Excellent! Thank ya sir, a beer is owed, I'll accept in a couple minutes when it allows me. Having to use Illustrator more now days still leaves me in a learning curve sometimes and this is one damn handy tip.

Comment: Glad to help :) Be aware.. overly distorting raster images *can* result in "broken pixels". Illustrator **never** interpolates raster data (Photoshop **always** does).

Comment: So maybe instead I should be asking, if I should create my vector stuff in Illustrator, then import it to Photoshop to do my Raster work and then use the result of that as my final print ready files?

Comment: That really depends on the project. If it's 20% raster and 80% vector, using Illustrator would be better.

Comment: Yea it's one of those big 4 panel fold out convention displays with each panel being roughly 21" Wide by 47" Tall to be printed CMYK at 120ppi (though I'm going to use 150ppi) so that's what I was thinking, but I havent done just graphics in years so am a bit rusty from doing development for so long instead, so any advice is always welcome.

Comment: At that size and resolution, you should be okay with something like a perspective distort. That will really only reduce a portion of the raster image, and reduction isn't generally an issue. It's enlarging during distortion that can be more problematic.

Comment: Good to know, thanks again for sparing the time man, cheers!

Comment: This only seems to work with embedded images, not linked. I'll maybe go and edit the answer.

Comment: Additionally, Envelope with Warp and using any warp (bend on 0%) is a bit easier, as you can just control the amount of distort with sliders and not have to adjust envelope curves. So I'll add that too.

Answer (score -2):

I just go effect - distort and transform - free distort, for quick fix.

Comment: Hi elle, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that doesn't work for raster images inside illustrator. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!